# Error using oauth2client in Python ServiceAccountCredentials has no attribute 'from_json_keyfile_name'

Tags: python, google-oauth, service-accounts

I have encountered a problem when using the oauth2client python library from google.  Specifically in the following function

```
def getConnection(self):
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']

    crendialFilePath = ConfigHandler().getCredentialsFileName(self.credential_file_name)
    print "crendialFilePath : " + crendialFilePath + "\n"
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(crendialFilePath, scopes)
    print "credentials : " + credentials + "\n"

    return discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'ServiceAccountCredentials' has no attribute 'from_json_keyfile_name'
```

This code used to work and as best I can tell the only thing that has changed was over the weekend my computer was upgraded from WIndows 7 to 10.

Here is the full error from python

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ABTests\BaseAnalysis.py", line 82, in run
    bq = BQDB("DATASET_DOESNT_MATTER", dbName="bq_"+self.game_name)
  File "C:\ABTests\RHIPythonUtils\Connectors\Database\bq.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.connection = self.getConnection()
  File "C:\ABTests\RHIPythonUtils\Connectors\Database\bq.py", line 53, in getConnection
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(crendialFilePath, scopes)
AttributeError: type object 'ServiceAccountCredentials' has no attribute 'from_json_keyfile_name'
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ABTests\BaseAnalysis.py", line 82, in run
    bq = BQDB("DATASET_DOESNT_MATTER", dbName="bq_"+self.game_name)
  File "C:\ABTests\RHIPythonUtils\Connectors\Database\bq.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.connection = self.getConnection()
  File "C:\ABTests\RHIPythonUtils\Connectors\Database\bq.py", line 53, in getConnection
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(crendialFilePath, scopes)
AttributeError: type object 'ServiceAccountCredentials' has no attribute 'from_json_keyfile_name'
```

I am not the original author of this code, and unfortunately the person who is recently left.

I looked through the documentation for the ServiceAccountCredentials within the oauth2client content and it seems that from_json_keyfile_name is a legitimate function, but not an attribute.  So I don't know why the error is saying it has no attribute for 'from_json_keyfile_name', unless that's a generic error for libraries when it can't find anything in that library/package that has a particular identifier.

My initial guess was that I needed to upgrade to the most recent version of the oauth2client, so I tried that and it didn't work.

I'd appreciate any help.  If anyone has any suggestions, even about what would constitute minimally viable code, that would be great.

I wonder if it's possible that someone on the system's admin side has maybe done something with the service accounts? Does that seem like a plausible explanation?

Answer (score 0):

What does your import look like? Ours is:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
```

That works like a charm.

Comment: I don't recall anymore and I don't have access to the code any longer.